# Setting background-color for Shell in css/default.css has no effect

Tags: css, eclipse-plugin, swt, e4

I'm stepping through "Eclipse 4 Plug-in Development by Example Beginner's Guide", and on section "Time for action – styling the UI with CSS".

The instructions here specify to edit "css/default.css" and add the following:

```
  Shell {
      background-color: blue;
  }
```

Unfortunately, this has no effect.  The background is still the default greyish color.

What can I do to debug this?

I tried running the "CSS Spy" tool, but I don't understand how to use it.

**Update**:

Here is my entire plugin.xml file:

```
<plugin>
   <extension id="product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product name="com.packtpub.e4.application"
    application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
     <property name="appName" value="com.packtpub.e4.application">
     </property>
  </product>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

The instructions in the section don't mention anything to do in here.  Where is there more information about what should be in here for this "simple" application?

**Update**:

So it appears that the book instructions neglected to mention the need for the "applicationCSS" property setting.  I added that manually as directed, and that fixed the problem.

The advice about "You should also specify the CSS name in the .product file" brings up additional questions.

It wasn't clear to me why this should also be done, in addition to setting the property in the plugin.xml file.  The field on that wizard page doesn't really explain what the value is used for, but it sounded to me like it has the same purpose as setting that property.

So, I tried removing the manual setting in the "plugin.xml" file and using the wizard to browse for the file.  I saved that and then inspected the "plugin.xml" file, as I expected that action in the wizard to populate that property.  There was no change.  I then looked at the wizard again and read the statement after that field, which said this (weird that selecting that text in the wizard and pressing Ctrl-C doesn't put the text into the clipboard):

```
'You must Synchronize (this word a hyperlink) the product's defining plug-in to ensure that the CSS file specified above is referenced in the plug-in's "org.eclipse.core.runtime.products" extension point.'
```

So I tried clicking that hyperlink.  That inserted the property into the plugin.xml file.  This brings up more questions.

If it's apparently important that "the CSS file specified above" is specified as the "applicationCSS" property in the "plugin.xml" file, why does the developer need to take a deliberate action to make this happen, as opposed to Eclipse just mirroring that value in the property?

The reference to the "org.eclipse.core.runtime.products" extension point is curious.  When I view the "plugin.xml" file for a non-e4 Eclipse application, I see tabs for "Extensions" and "Extension Points", but not when I view the wizard for this sample e4 application.  In addition, I don't see any reference to extensions or extension points in this generated "plugin.xml" file.

Is the value entered into the wizard used for ANYTHING except to use it to (manually) synchronize the value of the "applicationCSS" property?

Comment: Could be lots of things. First check there is a correct 'applicationCSS' in the 'product' entry in the main app plugin.xml

Comment: Doesn't appear to be there.  I added the plugin.xml.  I also noticed that the "Build" tab of the plugin.xml editor doesn't include the "css" directory in the "Binary build".

Comment: Most of your update is asking questions that only the Eclipse designers can answer. The plugin.xml does use the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products`  extension point.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an `applicationCSS` entry in the `product` entry in the plugin.xml (or a `cssTheme` if using themes) without this no CSS styling will be done.

Something like:

```xml
<extension
     id="product"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.products">
  <product
        name="greg.e4App2"
        application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application">
     <property
           name="applicationCSS"
           value="platform:/plugin/greg.e4App2/css/default.css">
     </property>
     <property
           name="appName"
           value="greg.e4App2">
     </property>
  </product>
</extension>
```

You should also specify the CSS name in the .product file on the 'Customization' tab in the 'CSS Styling' section.

Also check that the 'css' folder is included in the 'build.properties'

Comment: Ok, that works.  This brings up several questions, which are better phrased as updates on the question. Coming up.

Comment: New questions should be asked in new questions not updates to answered questions.

Comment: In general I'd agree, but the update is just more questions about how the "applicationCSS" property is set, which seem like good things to have in the same place.